# Embedded ext2 access library

Tags: c, embedded, ext2

Is there any os-independent read-write capable Ext2 FS access C library for embedded applications?

I'm looking for something that is similar to what [FatFS](http://elm-chan.org/fsw/ff/00index_e.html) is for FAT16/32.

I tried to port the corresponding Linux kernel filesystem module, but it is far from being easily portable.

Comment: Just so you know, ext2 is not considered a good filesystem for embedded and/or flash-based systems. Consider something made for embedded flash file systems like [JFFS2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jffs2) or similar.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg indeed, I don't need to stick to a specific FS here (I'm looking for any FS that can contain posix rwx access modes), but JFFS2 doesn't seem to have any existing usable libraries (except for Linux kernel code ): )